# How to install Datadog agent in AWS lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, datadog

We want to collect metrics from machines running AWS lambda in AWS. How can I get access to these machines and get DD agent installed on them.

Comment: You can't access the machines lambdas run on, and therefore, you can't run the datadog agent on them.  Lambda is different from eg elastic beanstalk; it's more like eg ELB in that you don't have access to the systems that run it.

Answer (score 2):

Lambda is serverless. Datadog agent is for the host. While running lambda you have absolutely no control over the host as you are not managing it.

Hence, You can monitor application running on lambda using datadog integration of lambda for the different application.

You may follow below link for AWS Integration of datadog.

Ref: https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/amazon_lambda/